# matplotlib without using animation function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm recently learning python of how to use matplotlib. My goal is to use matplotlib to show plot dynamically by reading a file ("somelog.log"). If there is a new line add to this log file, then update the total count of the bar plot that reflect to today's date.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
proddict = {}
prodlist = []
f = open ("somelog.log", 'r') 
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # read end of file

loop=True

while loop:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line: # if we don't get any data
        time.sleep(0.1)
        continue   #retry
    else:
        with open ("somelog.log", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                matches = re.findall(r'(\d+[-]\d+[-]\d+)', line)
                for match in matches:
                    count = proddict.get(match,0) 
                    proddict[match] = count + 1
        for k,v in proddict.iteritems():
            prodlist.append((k,v))
        prodlist = sorted(prodlist)
        plt.ion()
        W = np.arange(len(prodlist))
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for x,y in prodlist:
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
        plt.draw()
        rects1 = plt.bar(W, ys, color='green', align= 'center') 
        for rect in rects1:
            height = rect.get_height()
            plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d' % int(height),ha='center', va='bottom')
            plt.draw()

        plt.xticks(W, xs, rotation='vertical') 
        plt.title(' number of scripts executed (realtime)')
        plt.xlabel('Date')
        plt.ylabel('Usage')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.ylim(0,500) # that's the limit
        plt.legend(loc=0)

        plt.show()
```

What I got is below result:

[image: script output]

The issue that I'm having is:

When I first issue this script, it will not trigger the bar plot yet because it is waiting for the new line to add to log file ("somelog.log"). Once it detects a new line added, then it triggered the plot (as attached in pic).  However, when another new line add to somelog.log, it doesn't dynamically update the total count. (I'm expect the total number to change from 129 to 130 in the latest date shows in this pic)

Could someone please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that on the same logfile with the same data the script works when you run it the first time, but doesn't work when you rerun it again? What exactly happens, when you rerun it? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I can't use the animation function as my work has limitation and not able to install it in prod machines. So I'm looking for the solution that is not using the animation function.

Comment: @wombatonfire, what I'm try to accomplish is read the log file, if it detected a new line added to this new log file, then update the bar plot for today's date

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and, looking at the script output, it seems to work. So what exactly doesn't work? What is the problem?

Comment: @wombatonfire, the script only works when I executed another script once (as it looks for the new line of the log file), it opened the plot. So after I closed another script. Reopen it again, the bar plot doesn't update according (change from 129 to 130 dynamically)